# OpenGL renders boxes inside-out

Tags: opengl, glut

I'm trying to create 2 boxes in OpenGL, but they appear inside-out and sometimes they do not overlap correctly. Video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IVJu4zJFp7Q

I'm guessing it is a depth issue but I haven't been able to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the code I'm using to initialize:

```
glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);

glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE); 
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

Here is my distplay function
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

glPolygonMode( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL );

drawYellowBox();
drawBlueBox();
```

And the code I'm using to draw the shapes:

```
glPushMatrix();
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

        glColor3f(0.15, 0.15, 0.0);
        // draw front
        glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.5, 1.0);
        glVertex3f( 1.0, -1.5, 1.0);
        glVertex3f( 0.75,  1.5, 0.75);
        glVertex3f(-0.75,  1.5, 0.75);

        glColor3f(0.3, 0.3, 0.0);
        // draw back
        glVertex3f( 1.0, -1.5, -1.0);
        glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.5, -1.0);
        glVertex3f(-0.75,  1.5, -0.75);
        glVertex3f( 0.75,  1.5, -0.75);

        glColor3f(0.45, 0.45, 0.0);
        // draw left
        glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.5, -1.0);
        glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.5,  1.0);
        glVertex3f(-0.75,  1.5,  0.75);
        glVertex3f(-0.75,  1.5, -0.75);

        glColor3f(0.6, 0.6, 0.0);
        // draw right
        glVertex3f( 1.0, -1.5,  1.0);
        glVertex3f( 1.0, -1.5, -1.0);
        glVertex3f( 0.75,  1.5, -0.75);
        glVertex3f( 0.75,  1.5,  0.75);

        glColor3f(0.75, 0.75, 0.0);
        // draw top
        glVertex3f(-0.75,  1.5,  0.75);
        glVertex3f( 0.75,  1.5,  0.75);
        glVertex3f( 0.75,  1.5, -0.75);
        glVertex3f(-0.75,  1.5, -0.75);

        glColor3f(0.9, 0.9, 0.0);
        // draw bottom
        glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.5, -1.0);
        glVertex3f( 1.0, -1.5, -1.0);
        glVertex3f( 1.0, -1.5,  1.0);
        glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.5,  1.0);
    glEnd();

glPopMatrix();

glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0.0,2.5,0.0);
    glRotatef(joint_ui_data->getDOF(Keyframe::HEAD), 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);


    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

        glColor3f(0.0, 0.15, 0.15);
        // draw front face
        glVertex3f(-0.8, -0.45, 0.8);
        glVertex3f( 0.8, -0.45, 0.8);
        glVertex3f( 0.75,  0.45, 0.75);
        glVertex3f(-0.75,  0.45, 0.75);

        glColor3f(0.0, 0.3, 0.3);
        // draw back face
        glVertex3f( 0.8, -0.45, -0.8);
        glVertex3f(-0.8, -0.45, -0.8);
        glVertex3f(-0.75,  0.45, -0.75);
        glVertex3f( 0.75,  0.45, -0.75);

        glColor3f(0.0, 0.45, 0.45);
        // draw left face
        glVertex3f(-0.8, -0.45, -0.8);
        glVertex3f(-0.8, -0.45,  0.8);
        glVertex3f(-0.75,  0.45,  0.75);
        glVertex3f(-0.75,  0.45, -0.75);

        glColor3f(0.0, 0.6, 0.6);
        // draw right face
        glVertex3f( 0.8, -0.45,  0.8);
        glVertex3f( 0.8, -0.45, -0.8);
        glVertex3f( 0.75,  0.45, -0.75);
        glVertex3f( 0.75,  0.45,  0.75);

        glColor3f(0.0, 0.75, 0.75);
        // draw top
        glVertex3f(-0.75,  0.45,  0.75);
        glVertex3f( 0.75,  0.45,  0.75);
        glVertex3f( 0.75,  0.45, -0.75);
        glVertex3f(-0.75,  0.45, -0.75);

        glColor3f(0.0, 0.9, 0.9);
        // draw bottom
        glVertex3f(-0.8, -0.45, -0.8);
        glVertex3f(-0.8, -0.45,  0.8);
        glVertex3f( 0.8, -0.45,  0.8);
        glVertex3f( 0.8, -0.45, -0.8);
    glEnd();
glPopMatrix();
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem lies in the order you're sending your vertices.

As we can see in your code the vertex order of your *front side* is.

```
// Front
glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.5, 1.0);   // Left   Top
glVertex3f( 1.0, -1.5, 1.0);   // Right  Top
glVertex3f( 0.75,  1.5, 0.75); // Right  Bottom
glVertex3f(-0.75,  1.5, 0.75); // Left   Bottom
```

As we can see in that piece of code your sending the vertices **clockwise**. OpenGL by default reads all polygons **counterclockwise**. That is why all the opposite faces are removed/hidden (Culled away).

To fix this you can do 1 of 2 things.

1. Change the mode of [glFrontFace()](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glFrontFace.xml) so it becomes `GL_CW`, instead of `GL_CCW`. Though remember that the change will effect everything that comes after you call `glFrontFace(GL_CW)` so remember to call `glFrontFace(GL_CCW)` again if there at any other point you render something which have **counterclockwise** winding again.
2. Change the order you're sending the vertices in.

From

```
// Front
glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.5, 1.0);   // Left   Top
glVertex3f( 1.0, -1.5, 1.0);   // Right  Top
glVertex3f( 0.75,  1.5, 0.75); // Right  Bottom
glVertex3f(-0.75,  1.5, 0.75); // Left   Bottom
```

To

```
// Front
glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.5, 1.0);   // Left   Top
glVertex3f(-0.75,  1.5, 0.75); // Left   Bottom
glVertex3f( 0.75,  1.5, 0.75); // Right  Bottom
glVertex3f( 1.0, -1.5, 1.0);   // Right  Top
```

*Though if you already have tons of meshes it would probably be much easier simply to change the `glFrontFace` mode to `GL_CW`.*

## Extra

Also if you want to change which faces are being culled, you can also change the mode of [glCullFace](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glCullFace.xml), to either `GL_FRONT`, `GL_BACK` or `GL_FRONT_AND_BACK` the initial value is `GL_BACK`.

Remember you need to call `glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE)` to enable culling of polygons based on their vertex winding.

## Edit

If it's not a vertex winding problem, the it might (though it would be very weird), be a depth testing problem.

Add this code to your initialization code.

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't solve the problem. I tried reordering the vertices, but with no effect. Reverting back to the original vertices and changing the glFrontFace to CW still didn't fix the rendering.

Comment: This was my problem too. (Using Ubuntu 16.04, python GL and GLUT. I tested and isolated it by using GLUT to draw cubes instead of my own vertices; if GLUT's own cube are inside out then its not a winding problem but needs the depth flag turning on.)

Answer (score 2):

To fix this problem you will need to flip your faces around on your object or check you normals of the object at hand...

If you create a plane you will notice you can see through one side of it unless you invert normals to the view side or add a double sided solution...

I usually use away3d or three.js for 3D content...the principles are the same

Comment: I've tried reversing the order of the vertices for some of the faces, but no effect. Is this because of backface culling? I'm trying to disable it back-face culling.

Comment: yeah that could be a possibility, I would of much rather put my answer in a comment but i cant comment on question yet.. try looking through away3D website forums general problems have the same solutions just implemented a bit different

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. I was enabling depth testing in my initGlut() function instead of the initGl() function.

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```